# Декларация ассоциативного массива

Tags: typescript

Ко мне приходит объект такого вида

```
{
  "1": obj1,
  "5": obj2,
  "98": obj3,
  .......
}
```

`obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3` - объекты идентичной структуры. Я могу как-то на TypeScript описать общий объект? Пока приходит в голову только такое

```
type Response = obj[]
```

Но TypeScript отказывается приводить объект к массиву

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать декларацию индексированного типа

```
interface obj {
    data: string;
}

interface Response {
    [key: number]: obj;
}

const test: Response = {
    "1": {
        data: "s"
    },
    "5": {
        data: "st"
    },
};
```